# How can I iterate through rows of web form using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, range, nested-for-loop

Please I have a web form that I use selenium script to autofill in data row by row. Each time I run **add_event_button**, a new row is created, then I autofill the **date_field** to the **remarks_field**. All the fields within one row have similar **ID** attributes. The only difference is when you click the variable **add_event_button**, the new row has an ID increment of 1 across all fields.

Here is what I have done:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

add_event_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-voyage-log-12780"]/div[2]/a[2]'))).click()
time.sleep(2)

date_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#WGItem02_voyage_log-25_4')))
date_field.send_keys(date_time_row[1]) 


location_field = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'WGItem09_voyage_log-2_4'))
location_field.select_by_index(8)


event_field = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'WGItem04_voyage_log-2_4'))
event_field.select_by_index(4)


subevent_field = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'WGItem05_voyage_log-2_4'))
subevent_field.select_by_index(3)

remarks_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#WGItem06_voyage_log-2_4')))
remarks_field.send_keys(remarks_data_col[1])
```

How do I iterate through the above block of code to run up to 20 times. For example; `WGItem05_voyage_log-2_4` will run till it stops at `WGItem05_voyage_log-20_4` and `remarks_field.send_keys(remarks_data_col[1])` runs till `remarks_field.send_keys(remarks_data_col[20])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(2,21):
    remarks_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='WGItem06_voyage_log-{i}_4']")))
    remarks_field.send_keys(remarks_data_col[i-1])
```

Did you mean looping it like so and using f string to access the element with that xpath.